# what is the best wording to describe a link which opens/closes table in a horizontal way

Tags: terminology

in my application I need to display table in 2 modes
"simple" and "advanced"
for this purpose I added a link above the table 
clicking on it will display more columns in the table in a horizontal way (the first click will add the columns the second will remove them)
you can find example in the attached link

http://ndmtjv.axshare.com/#p=screen1

the question is what is the best term for this link
one possible option is 
1. "Expand table/Collapse table"
the  pros are that it is a common used term  to display more information, the cons are that it is mostly used  to show sub-items, not extra columns.
2. "show More/Hide"
the pros are that it can be used in a neutral way to describe display/hide of extra information, the cons are that it is not related to the word "table" and users will not have an immediate connection between the word and the action behind it

I will appreciate your suggestions

Comment: The link points to your local network, it will not work for us.

Comment: I think you answered your question with your own second line: "Display more columns." Or just "More Columns."

Answer (score 2):

Best thing you can do is **use phrase that is specific**. For example if your table lists banana's, and after you click the expand button you want to show bananas quantity you can use label "show quantity".

When you are specific users will know what to expect when they click there, while general lables does not reveal what information exactly will be displayed.

However if you can't be specific you can use one of the following:

- Show details / Close
- More details / Hide
- More info / Hide